# How to make a force field concentrate only on a specified area?

Tags: particles, physics, force-fields

For example if I use 3 different object emitting particles, I only want 1 of them to get affected by the force field.

[image]

I tried adjusting the area to be concentrated, but the force field affects everything which is in the same layer.

[image]

These are the settings that I’ve done to adjust where the force field should take effect.

Comment: Pleas tell me if I'm not clear with my question.

Comment: Your setup seems to work for me. Are you asking how to do this without depending on the particle systems being separated in space?

Comment: I wanted only the object in the middle to make its particles to flow along the wind force field, not the other two. And the settings that I've done above is not working as I said.

Comment: You don't have a fall-off power defined. I think that it is cumulative

Comment: Can you explain what these parameters mean or show me where to look? I haven't understood them before when reading the manual. Visuals help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the [*Effector Group*](http://blender.org/manual/physics/particles/physics/introduction.html#field-weights) to limit the force fields which can affect a given particle system:

1. Add an empty (or really anything that's not a force field)
2. With the empty selected, create a group (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>)
3. Specify this group as the *Effector group* for the systems which you do **not** want to be affected by any force fields:

   [image]
4. Optionally delete the empty.

Result:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- Place the force in a group
- Use an effector group name in the Field Weights