# Generic Movie dissolve (sand effect)

Tags: text-object

I search a way to dissolve a generic movie like sand effect. I animated my generic movie (down to up). But when a line come to the top of the screen I would like my text is dissolving like sand effect (wind force field left to right) and some particle take time to go to the right.

I work on Blender Render.

Currently, I am creating a Text object, convert it in a mesh and apply ParticleSystem. I add a wind force field. But when my animation start, all of my text is dissolving (Particle start at 1). Is it possible to put a force field in a tube not only the parameter, but in a cube for example and the wind work only in this cube ?

If I apply keyframe (keyframe on the particle start) on my text. When the text are near the wind the wind tube, it's works, each line dissolve. But if I change my text I need to restart all of the configuration, keyframes, etc.

I follow the tutorial from blender diplom [web](http://blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/all-tutorials/394-tutorial-dissolve-your-logo-in-blender-262.html?start=1) and some other example on web but I don't have the solution :
[web link 1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36355/how-to-make-a-force-field-concentrate-only-on-a-specified-area) and [web link 2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46830/beginner-how-do-i-make-force-field-affect-only-a-certain-area-of-hair)

**Is it possible to have a text scrolling where each line is dissolving when this line is on the top of the screen with Blender (Render or Cycle).**

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution (the best way is playing with all parameters). I think it is a good way to do what I want :-).

Step 1 :

- Add a cube
- Add a wind force field
- Add a plane (for particles)

Step 2 :

- Subdivision Surface on the plane -> to have more Faces for particles.
- Add ParticleSystem on the plane and just put the same Face number in Emission number.

Step 3 :

- Put the wind Force Field in the cube
- Rotate (R|Y|90) the wind
- Add Physics Collision on the cube

  -> Set Force Fields Absorption : 1.00 (maximum)
- Wind Force Field

  -> In Physics : Collision -> Check Absorption
  -> In Physics : Change the Strength to see the particle movement

When the plane are not in the cube, with gravity, they fall on Z axis. Create an animation on the cube (with Wind) or on the plane. When the plane are in the cube, particles fall on Z axis with a movment on the right.

Now I can create my text and animate all :-).

Hope this solution is good and maybe can help someone else :-).